# How to determine program complexity in Big-O when adding to a full ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, big-o, complexity-theory

I am working through a practice exam for my Computer Science class. However, I am not sure about the question below.

> Consider four different approaches to re-sizing an array-based list data-structure.
>   In each case, when we want to add() an item to the end of the array, but it is full, we
>   create a new array and then copy elements from the old one into the new one. For each of
>   the following choices about how big to make the new array, give the resulting complexity
>   of adding to the end of the list, in big-O terms:
>
> (i) increase array size by 1 item.
>
> (ii) Increase array size by 100 items.
>
> (iii) Double the array size.
>
> (iv) Triple the array size.

Since you call the same `System.arraycopy()` method reach time regardless, wouldn't the complexity be the same for each?

Comment: The wording of the question is not entirely clear. I suspect that the [amortized costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) are what is asked for. In this regards, the four methods will have different amortized costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since you call the same System.arraycopy() method reach time regardless, wouldn't the complexity be the same for each?

Yes, and no.

Yes - when you actually do the copy, the cost of the copy will be similar in all cases.

(They are not exactly the same if you include the cost of allocating and initializing the array.  It takes more space and time to allocate and initialize an array of `2 * N` elements than for `N + 1` elements.  But you will only be copying N elements into the array.)

No - the different strategies result in the array copies happening a different number of times.  If you do a complete complexity analysis for a sequence of operations, you will find that options 3 and 4 have a different complexity to 1 and 2.

(And it is worth noting that 2 will be faster than 1, even though they have the same complexity.)

The typical analysis for this involves working out the *total* costs for something like this:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    list.add(new Object());
}
```

---

<sup>(Hint: the analysis may be given as an example in your recommended "data structures and algorithms" textbook, or your lecture notes.  If so, that is what you should be revising (before doing practice exams!)  If not, Google for "complexity amortized arraylist" and you will find examples.)</sup>

Comment: IMO, 2 should be faster than 1. Could you please correct the typo?

Comment: @YogiDevendra - Well spotted.  Fixed.